# Why don't databases or language platforms return strongly typed classes when executing a query?

Tags: .net, database, orm

Why is it that when querying a database I don't just get back a strongly typed class (or list of classes) with all the fields requested and proper Intellisense?

In other words, "SELECT * FROM Employees" would give me a list of Employees objects with Intellisense.

I know there are ORM solutions or even simpler object mapper type solutions (Massive, Dapper, etc...) but it would seem that this should be *basic* database or language platform functionality?

One reason I can think of is the different languages, but then perhaps the data provider should just take care of it, and you have the languages platforms like .NET which should shield from it...

Another reason is that languages are not capable of dynamic runtime class creation, that an Intellisense doesn't seem to support such a beast (but it should!).

What are the technical details preventing this from the here and now in my compiler/database?  Are there tools that allow me to do this right now?

Comment: What should be the result of `"SELECT * FROM " + tableName`? How could Intellisense possibly deal with that?

Comment: On one hand, you say "I know there are ORMs (but let's ignore those)" (paraphrased) and on the other hand you say "Are there tools that allow me to do this right now?" Hmmm....

Comment: Does anyone else get a chuckle from the OP's name? I know... I'm bad! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it that when querying a database I don't just get back a
>   strongly typed class (or list of classes) with all the fields
>   requested and proper Intellisense?

Because there is an [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) between OOP and SQL.

> I know there are ORM solutions or even simpler object mapper type
>   solutions (Massive, Dapper, etc...) but it would seem that this should
>   be basic database or language platform functionality?

No, that's why you have ORMs.

> Another reason is that languages are not capable of dynamic runtime
>   class creation, that an Intellisense doesn't seem to support such a
>   beast (but it should!).

.NET languages are mostly statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, a database is decoupled from the client.  There is a call interface and a result set - you cannot anticipate it without making the call.

Even with LINQ, that metadata is coming from a separate interrogation of the database which the project has been made aware of, usually using a "formatonly" option.

I know it's frustrating, but it kind of comes with the territory of being decoupled.

And this is all before you start to consider whether there are different design patterns in relational databases versus object models and whether implementation details like link tables even have a corresponding class in the object oriented world.